# Recyclerview not returning the data

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, android-recyclerview

```
public class HomeScreen_Contacts extends Fragment {

TextView noUsersText;

ProgressDialog mProgressDialogue;

FirebaseAuth mAuth;
FirebaseUser currentUser;
String UID;

RecyclerView mUsersList;
View rootView;

DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AllUsers, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);

    mProgressDialogue = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    mProgressDialogue.setMessage("Loading...");
    mProgressDialogue.show();

    noUsersText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.noUsersText);
    mUsersList = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.usersList);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    UID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    mUsersList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mUsersList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    Query query=mDatabaseReference.orderByChild("Name");
    mUsersList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<AllUsers> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<AllUsers>()
                    .setQuery(mDatabaseReference, AllUsers.class)
                    .build();


    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AllUsers, UsersViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull AllUsers model) {
            holder.setName(model.getName());
            holder.setStatus(model.getStatus());
        }

        @Override
        public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.all_users_layout, parent, false);

            return new UsersViewHolder(view);
        }
    };
    mUsersList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    return rootView;
}
public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;
    public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        TextView mDisplayName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.display_name);
        mDisplayName.setText(name);
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        TextView mDisplayStatus = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.display_status);
        mDisplayStatus.setText(status);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
}
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(firebaseRecyclerAdapter != null) {
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

}

I can't figure out where i have went wrong... And also firebaserecycler rules have changed and its kind of different from the old one so im not even sure whether this logic is correct... i have looked up through different tutorials and got up to this point for this firebaserecyclerview...please help... if need more code like the database structure please ask... Thanks in advance

Getting this error if i remove setHasFixedSize(true);

```
03-31 19:53:53.540 8593-8631/com.appmaster.akash.messageplus E/HAL: 
hw_get_module_by_class: module name gralloc
03-31 19:53:53.541 8593-8631/com.appmaster.akash.messageplus E/HAL: 
hw_get_module_by_class: module name gralloc
03-31 19:53:55.313 8593-8593/com.appmaster.akash.messageplus 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.appmaster.akash.messageplus, PID: 8593

com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields 
with conflicting case sensitivity for property: image

at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeas.zzqb(Unknown Source)

at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeas.<init>(Unknown Source)

at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzear.zzf(Unknown Source)

at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzear.zzb(Unknown Source)

at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzear.zza(Unknown Source)

at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)

at 
com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotP 
arser. 
java:23)

at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotP 
arser.java:14)

at 
com.firebase.ui.common.BaseCachingSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(BaseCachingS  
apshotParser.java:32)

at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseObservableSnapshotArray.get(BaseObservableSn 
apshotArray.java:45)

at 
com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecycler 
Adapter.java:103)

at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:118)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6482)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6515)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5458)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5724)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3109)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18827)
                                                                               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
                                                                               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18827)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1630)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18827)
                                                                               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
                                                                               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18827)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18827)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18827)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18827)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18827)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                            at an
```

AllUsersActivity

```
package com.appmaster.akash.messageplus;
```

/**
 * Created by Dota 2 on 03-02-2018.
 */

public class AllUsers {

```
public String Name;
public String Status;
public String Image;

public AllUsers (){

}

public AllUsers(String name, String status, String Image) {
    Name = name;
    Status = status;
    Image = Image;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return Status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    Status = status;
}

public String getImage() {
    return Image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    Image = image;
}
```

}

Comment: That's not how to use a ViewHolder, you should declare all the views from the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AllUsers, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);

    mProgressDialogue = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    mProgressDialogue.setMessage("Loading...");
    mProgressDialogue.show();

    noUsersText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.noUsersText);
    mUsersList = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.usersList);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    UID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    mUsersList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mUsersList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<AllUsers> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<AllUsers>()
                    .setQuery(mDatabaseReference, AllUsers.class)
                    .build();

    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AllUsers, UsersViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) { }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull AllUsers model) { }
    };
    mUsersList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
}
```

Comment: Still not returning data

Comment: Make your fields private, bacouse you have get/set methods.

Comment: Omg.... i cant believe such a small error... man i owe u loads.... thank u so much

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to also override the `getItemCount()` function.

This function should return the number of items your `RecyclerView` have. **Otherwise**, the adapter think you have 0 items.

Comment: @Override
                public int getItemCount() {
                    int itemCount = getItemCount();
                return itemCount;
            }
is this correct.. im not sure

Comment: No, that's a recursion (your'e calling the function you just made). You need to return the number of items you have in your 'RecyclerView'. a basic solution would be to just return a hardcoded number (such as 4).
From my understanding your whole adapter understanding is wrong, try following some tutorials. [link1](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a new version of the FirebaseUI were you have to start listening and stop listening for data so it appears in the Recycler View.

You need to listen to the data first:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
}
```

Explained in depth here:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#firebaserecycleradapter-lifecycle

Comment: Non-static method 'startListening()' cannot be referenced from a static context..... ERROR.. what do i do

Comment: where are you adding it? Add this line `firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();` before setAdapter

Comment: @SarahJackson remove `mUsersList.setHasFixedSize(true);` for the data to appear also